# Find 3 consecutive missing integers from an array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

below is the code to find out the missing numbers, but need to select first 3 consecutive numbers from missings

```
array=[0,1,4,5,9,10]
start=0
end=15

missings=[]
for i in range(start,end):        
    if i not in array:
        missings.append(i)
```

output: [6,7,8]

Comment: What's the issue you're having?

Comment: His issue is that he needs the next step of his program that determines which 3 consecutive numbers are missing. He knows all the numbers that are missing though

Comment: Is the array sorted with no duplicates?

Comment: You can try using the array indices: if the value in the array is larger than its index by 3 or more, then there are 3 missing numbers starting at this index. Does this help?

Comment: This site is to help you in case you have a problem. We are not here to "work" for you and provide you with the solution. First try it yourself and show some effort in solving it by yourself. As a hint: use the search function how to detect consecutive numbers. That problem should already be solved somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
array=[0,1,4,5,9,10]
start=0
end=15

missings=[]
for i in range(start,end-1):        
    if i not in array:
        if i+1 not in array:
            if i+2 not in array:
                missings.append(i)
                missings.append(i+1)
                missings.append(i+2)
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list in ascending order, then compare the values in the array with their neighbor to determine if there is a gap >3.

```
def find_missing(arr):
    sorted_list = sorted(arr)
    # Set our lowest value for comparing
    curr_value = sorted_list[0]
    for i in range(1,len(sorted_list)):
        # Compare the previous value to the next value to determine if there is a difference of atleast 4 (6-3 = 3 but we are only missing numbers 4 and 5)
        if (sorted_list[i] - curr_value) > 3:
            # Return on the first 3 consecutive missing numbers
            return [curr_value+1, curr_value+2, curr_value+3]
        curr_value = sorted_list[i]
    # Return an empty array if there is not 3 consecutive missing numbers
    return []
```

This function works based on the length of the array and the largest number. If there is a need for a specified end value in case all elements in the array do not have a gap of three except for the largest element and the end value, it can be passed as a parameter with some minor modifications.

```
def find_missing(arr, start_val=0, end_val=0):
    # Sorting a list alters the source, so make a copy to not alter the original list
    sorted_list = sorted(arr)
    curr_value = sorted_list[0]
    last_value = sorted_list[-1]
    # Make sure start val is the lowest number, otherwise use lowest number
    if  start_val < curr_value and (curr_value - start_val) > 3:
        return [start_val, start_val+1, start_val+2]
    for i in range(1,len(sorted_list)):
        # Compare the previous value to the next value to determine if there is a difference of atleast 4 (6-3 = 3 but we are only missing numbers 4 and 5)
        if (sorted_list[i] - curr_value) > 3:
            # Return on the first 3 consecutive missing numbers
            return [curr_value+1, curr_value+2, curr_value+3]
        curr_value = sorted_list[i]
    # If there is an end_value set that has a gap between the largest number and is larger than the last value
    if end_val > last_value and (end_val - last_value) > 3:
        return [last_value+1, last_value+2, last_value+3]
    else:
        # Return an empty array if there is not 3 consecutive missing numbers
        return []
```